# CSS: Обводка картинки волной

Tags: css, svg, изображения, border

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, подскажите, как реализовать вот это на css, имеется картинка-квадрат, нужно сделать такую вот обводку волнами

Comment: Возможно ли как-то сделать с использованием SVG

Comment: Я думаю, здесь будет не сложно https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Но как закруглить эти острые углы не знаю но как пример покажу

чуть чуть по другому но в `div` в [песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/svberzxn/)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1022 1002" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" 
           patternTransform="matrix(.5 -.005 .0049 .49 -625 -57)"
           width="1150.8885" 
          height="816.77674"
          patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           
     <image x="6.2e-14" 
            y="2e-14" 
      width="1151" 
      height="817" 
      preserveAspectRatio="none" 
      xlink:href="https://img4.goodfon.ru/original/2048x1365/3/df/devushka-nozhki-amandine-sidit-dzhinsy-zhivotik.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 
 <g transform="translate(591 61)">
  <path d="m-429-61c-22 18-46 35-79 38-15 28-28 57-59 72-1.5 41-11 70-24 94 13 23 23 50 22 84 23 19 48 37 58 73 27 8 54 17 84 38 38-8.5 66-6.5 90 2.1 28-28 56-40 84-40 17-32 36-60 61-73-4.4-31 0.19-59 21-84-18-29-24-58-21-88-30-20-47-48-60-79-32-0.69-57-18-81-38-30 5.4-59 11-97 1e-6z" style="fill:url(#pattern);"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать по вашему примеру

Также нашел еще такой способ - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/
Может кому-то пригодится в будущем

Comment: mask в css не очень поддерживается хотя работает в современных браузерах

Comment: Мне поддержку в ie < 10 не нужна, там просто круг будет, в остальных вроде все работает